# How to pass bean class to a test method in testng?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, dataprovider, testng-dataprovider

I have an Excel Util which reads all the data from excel sheet. The excel sheet has 10 columns like time, sourceType, tid, message, severity,
lastModify, entityName, operationType, replayId, recordIds.

My DataProvider has code something like this which returns all the 10 columns and their values.

```
@DataProvider(name="googleData")
public static Object[][] testData() {
    String filePath = "/Users/TestUser/Workspace/FixProject/ExcelCheck/src/test/resources/excelreader.xlsx";
    Object[][] arrayObject = excelFileUtils.getExcelData(filePath, "excelreader");
    return arrayObject;
}
```

In My TestMethod, I have to pass all these 10 columns or else it wont allow me to run. Instead I want to create a Bean Class and pass something like this to my test method

```
@Test(dataProvider = "googleData", dataProviderClass = DataProviders.class)
public void testGoogleData(BeanClass object) {
System.out.println(object.getTid());
```

}

How do we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using the dataProvider you have, your test method is going to run 10 times for each object in the array.

What you can do is to create an object, convert your dataProvider into that object and than use it your test method code.

```
Object myDataHelper = null;

@Test()
public void testGoogleData(BeanClass object) {
myDataHelper = convertDataProviderToObject();
// use it here in a for/for each loop
System.out.println(object.getTid());
}
```

Comment: For your approach, In the Test Annotation we are not passing the data provider. I want to pass my data provider to the excel sheet. The excel sheet returns an Object which is 2-D that contains all the 10 columns from my excel sheet. Further more, I want to map all those 10 columns to a bean class Object which should again return a 2-D object( because data providers allows Object[][] as return type).

Comment: When you use dataProvider - it is being called for every item in the 2-D array. You must trick the system and use another object that goes over every element in the array. This is how the dataProvider works using TestNG.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Object[][] read_excel(String Sheet_Name) throws Exception
    {
        File obj = new File("./src/main/java/com/Demo/TestData/Test_Data.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(obj);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet(Sheet_Name);
        int row_number  = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        int column_number = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        Object data[][] = new Object[row_number][column_number];
        wb.close();
        for(int i=0; i<row_number; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<column_number; j++)
            {
                data[i][j] = sheet.getRow(i + 1).getCell(j).toString();
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

---

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] getDataFromExcel() throws Exception
{  Object[][] data = Utility.read_excel("Admin_Credentials");//Sheet name
    return data;
} 
@Test(dataProvider="getDataFromExcel")
```

Comment: I have the same code. The problem is it requires all the columns to be passed to my test method. I can't able to use a Bean class and call that as it says, You have 10 objects from the data provider and the test calls only 1 object.

Answer (score 0):

It is supported in [QAF-TestNG extension](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#data-provider-extension). You can have [one or more complex object](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html#method-arguments-java-only) argument in your test method while using inbuilt or custom data provider. For excel your code may look like below:

```
@QAFDataProvider(dataFile = "resources/data/googletestdata.xls")
@Test
public void testGoogleData(BeanClass object) {
   System.out.println(object.getTid());
}
```

For custom data provider it may look like below:

```
@QAFDataProvider
@Test(dataProvider = "googleData", dataProviderClass = DataProviders.class)
public void testGoogleData(BeanClass object) {
   System.out.println(object.getTid());
}
```

You need to make sure that,properties name in your bean class must match column names (in any order). When using custom data provider you need to return Iterator for `List` of `Map<String, Object>` or Object[][] having Map, refer [few example](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/blob/master/test/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/impl/CustomDataProvider.java) if you required to create custom data provider.

Comment: it didn't work with the approach-1. Could you please try and let me know? I am getting an error, "The data provider is trying to pass 3 methods but the method testGoogleData takes 1. The excel sheet has 3 columns for Name, tid, Email and 1 row.I also created BeanClass that has these 3 members and respective getters and setters.

Comment: May be you are not using qaf 2.1.14. [qaf-example-project](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/files/2985945/qaf-example-project.zip) is working sample you can try and refer.